# Kali Linux VirtualBox Header Problems

Tags: kali-linux, linux-headers

I'm trying to install VirtualBox guest additions on Kali Linux 2018.1 with the kernel version 4.14.0
But when I try to install them from the guest additions ISO by running the VBoxLinuxAdditions.run file it gives the error for missing the `linux-headers-4.14.0-kali3-amd64` header.
When I search the apt cache it doesn't come up but I have the 4.15.0 header installed. I also tried to install `linux-headers-amd64` but it says that `linux-headers-4.14.0-kali3-amd64` has no installation candidate
[Kali docs](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-virtual-box-guest) say I should use the `virtualbox-guest-x11` package and I installed it. But after a reboot absolutely nothing happens and the guest additions still don't work. I even tried installing the old headers manually but that bricked my installation. I'm quite lost and I didn't find any other solutions to this problem.
I would appreciate help.
EDIT: I added some more information but please tell me what would you like more.
EDIT 2: Downvoting isn't going to help improve my question. Please give me pointers and I'll improve it

Comment: Please add enough details so that community can troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kali Linux is based on Debian testing and therefor the injectable ISO from virtualbox will usually be for an earlier version of the Linux kernel. I want to generalize this answer as this same problem will **always** apply to Kali Linux so long as its based on Debian testing (aka Sid).

If you do not need x support install `virtualbox-guest-utils` or with x support `virtualbox-guest-x11` Or if you wish to use guest additions as provided by oracle install `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` package. (if you install the latter you have to know how to mount the iso on the guest yourself and install it like you just did.) Otherwise you do not need to do anything after install except maybe reboot the guest.